# Numix-Circle Theme: Word Online does not get recognized

Tags: gnome, themes, icons, chromebook, icon-themes

Some of my applications, f.e. `Qpdfview`, `JabRef`, `Word`- `Excel`- and `PowerPoint`-Online don't get correctly recognized, so the default icons get used, and not the `Numix-Circle` Icons.

I manually changed the desktop entries, which isn't a huge deal, but those icons are now very blurry (I used the .svg icons in the 'scalable' folder).

Is there any way those applications can/will get recognized so the correct Icon is automatically used?

(I also receive a: `gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.` error for Circle-Icon theme, which should be caused by whitespaces in some file names)

EDIT: Got the icons clear and crispy. I had the `Icons` entry in the .desktop files point directly onto the .svg file. Changed it to only the name of the icon, e.g. from `../Numix-Circle/scalable/apps/ms-word.svg` to `ms-word`.